# Nondeterministic behavior by LLVM/LLDB (XCode 5.1.1)

Tags: c++, xcode, llvm

**Please do not comment on things like how I should pass by reference etc. This piece of code is totally experimental. Focus on the non-deterministic behavior.**

The title sounds very skeptical, I know.

Here is what is going on:

```
vector<int> find_permutation2(vector<int> v) {
    int k = (int)v.size() - 1;
    while(k >= 0 && v[k] >= v[k + 1])
        k--;
    if(k == -1) return vector<int>();

    int i;
    for(i = (int)v.size() - 1; i > k; i--) {
        if(v[i] > v[k])
            break;
    }

    vector<int> r(v);
    std::swap(r[k], r[i]);
    std::reverse(r.begin() + k + 1, r.end());
    return r;
}

int main() {
    vector<int> foo = {2,3,4,1,0};
    vector<int> bar = find_permutation2(foo);
    default_random_engine g;
    uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(5,10);
    for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        int size = dist(g);
        vector<int> p(size);
        iota(p.begin(), p.end(), 0);
        shuffle(p.begin(), p.end(), g);

        //
        // BREAKPOINT ON THE FOLLOWING LINE
        // I continue until p == {2,3,4,1,0}
        //
        vector<int> r = find_permutation2(p);
        vector<int> pc = vector<int>(p);
        bool res = std::next_permutation(pc.begin(), pc.end());

        if(res)
            assert(pc == r);
        else
            assert(r.size() == 0);
}
```

Now please check my LLDB output for some queries (notice different outputs produced):

```
(lldb) expr find_permutation2(p)
    (std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> >) $0 = size=5 {
        [0] = 2
        [1] = 4
        [2] = 0
        [3] = 1
        [4] = 3
    }

(lldb) expr find_permutation2(p)
    (std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> >) $2 = size=5 {
        [0] = 2
        [1] = 3
        [2] = 4
        [3] = 1
        [4] = 0
    }

(lldb) expr find_permutation2(foo)
    (std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> >) $0 = size=5 {
        [0] = 2
        [1] = 3
        [2] = 4
        [3] = 1
        [4] = 0
    }

(lldb) expr find_permutation2(foo)
    (std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> >) $2 = size=5 {
        [0] = 2
        [1] = 4
        [2] = 0
        [3] = 1
        [4] = 3
    }
```

BTW, it is not just the LLDB. If I run the code, assertion sometimes fails and sometimes doesn't fail on the given input `{2,3,4,1,0}`. Output seems to be totally random between those two above.

**Edit - The Explicit Question**

Can someone tell me why I'm getting differing outputs for the same input to the same function call?

Comment: There actually is an implicit question being asked.

Comment: Why not make it explicit, given that this is a question+answer site whose value depends on meaningful, clear posts that are useful to future visitors?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this code

```
int k = (int)v.size() - 1;
while(k >= 0 && v[k] >= v[k + 1])
```

`v[k+1]` refers to an element beyond the end of `v` on the first iteration, which gives undefined behaviour.